# httpclient3.1 can request data but httpclient4.x cannot

Tags: java, http

**Why 3.1 can request data normally, but using 4.5 will throw Circular redirect**

**Do I need any additional configuration to make it compatible with 3.1？**

**In 4.5 I set setCircularRedirectsAllowed and setMaxRedirects but it still throws an exception**

httpclient3.1:

```
    private static Document requestData(String url, CookieStore cookieStore, String proxyIp, String proxyPort, String userAgent) {
        HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
        List<Header> headers = new ArrayList<Header>();
        headers.add(new Header("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3"));
        headers.add(new Header("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9"));
        headers.add(new Header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0"));
        headers.add(new Header("connection", "keep-alive"));
        StringBuilder tmpcookies = new StringBuilder();
        for (Cookie cookie : cookieStore.getCookies()) {
            tmpcookies.append(cookie.getName()).append("=").append(cookie.getValue()).append(";");
        }
        headers.add(new Header("Cookie", tmpcookies.toString()));
        headers.add(new Header("Host", "Host"));
        headers.add(new Header("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1"));
        headers.add(new Header("User-Agent", userAgent));
        hc.getHostConfiguration().getParams().setParameter("http.default-headers", headers);
        hc.getHostConfiguration().setProxy(proxyIp, Integer.parseInt(proxyPort));
        hc.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setConnectionTimeout(10000);
        hc.getHttpConnectionManager().getParams().setSoTimeout(10000);

        GetMethod get = new GetMethod(url);
        try {
            int code = hc.executeMethod(get);
            if (code == 200) {
                InputStream inputStream = get.getResponseBodyAsStream();
                String result = StringUtil.inputStreamToString(inputStream);
                return Jsoup.parse(result);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

httpclient4.x :

```
    private static Document requestData(String url, CookieStore cookieStore, RequestConfig defaultRequestConfig, String userAgent, String uniSocCreCode) {
        CloseableHttpClient hc = HttpClients.custom().build();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        get.addHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3");
        get.addHeader("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.9");
        get.addHeader("Cache-Control", "max-age=0");
        get.addHeader("connection", "keep-alive");
        StringBuilder tmpcookies = new StringBuilder();
        for (Cookie cookie : cookieStore.getCookies()) {
            tmpcookies.append(cookie.getName()).append("=").append(cookie.getValue()).append(";");
        }
        get.addHeader("Cookie", tmpcookies.toString());
        get.addHeader("Host", "Host");
        get.addHeader("Upgrade-Insecure-Requests", "1");
        get.addHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
        get.setConfig(defaultRequestConfig);
        try {
            CloseableHttpResponse response = hc.execute(get);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                InputStream inputStream = response.getEntity().getContent();
                String result = StringUtil.inputStreamToString(inputStream);
                return Jsoup.parse(result);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("error", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

error(4.x):

```
Caused by: org.apache.http.client.CircularRedirectException: Circular redirect to 'https://www.qcc.com/firm/a4eb893fb989c8cdd7a73809d5b65715.html'
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.getLocationURI(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:193)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRedirectStrategy.getRedirect(DefaultRedirectStrategy.java:223)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:126)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    ... 68 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Still think it is a version problem
move to org.apache.httpcomponents.client5 » httpclient5 solved the problem

Comment: I still want to know the cause of the problem, if anyone knows